# Manipulating a Control located in Listview.ItemTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF MVVM project. I have a Listview that has an Image and a MediaElement inside a Grid. My goal is to play the video when the mouse is over the Image.
Because the controls are in an ItemTemplate, i can't access them from code behind:

```
private void photoC_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //mediaplayerC doesnt exist

}
```

My XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="photosListC" Background="Beige" Padding="15"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PhotosList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="mainGrid" MouseEnter="mainGrid_MouseEnter">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <MediaElement  Name="mediaplayerC" Source="{Binding VidSource}" 
                                   Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="2" LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                                   MouseEnter="mediaplayerC_MouseEnter" >
                    </MediaElement>
                    <Image  Name="photoC" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="3" MouseEnter="photoC_MouseEnter">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage  UriSource="{Binding ImSource}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is `sender`? if event handler is called, sender has to be a `MediaElement`. make a cast then

Comment: but it is the handler of the Image's MouseOver event, and i need to adress the MediaElement in it.

Comment: You could use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to find the UI element rendered for the specified DataContext, or traverse the Visual Tree to find the item, but in this case it might be easier to just bind the `MediaElement` to something like `Image.CommandParameter` or `Image.Tag`